# Calling functions in MultiSigWallet with onlyWallet modifier

Tags: web3js, wallets, multisignature

I've deployed a MultiSigWallet from [ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/solidity/MultiSigWallet.sol). How can I call functions with onlyWallet modifier?

```
modifier onlyWallet() {
    if (msg.sender != address(this))
        revert();
    _;
}
```

Does the `address` variable need to be an account address or can it be a contract address?

```
var data = multisig.replaceOwner.call(web3.eth.accounts[1], web3.eth.accounts[2], {from: address}, function(err, res) { console.log(res.toString())});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onlyWallet` modifier means that a transaction needs to be confirmed with multiple signatures first. In order to do that you need to:

1.Submit transaction and get `transactionId`

```
function submitTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
```

2.Confirm it with the required number of confirmations from owner accounts:

```
function confirmTransaction(uint transactionId)
```

3.Execute transaction:

```
function executeTransaction(uint transactionId)
```

Comment: I found the answer. See below

Answer (score 1):

onlyWallet transaction is not for confirmation , it's checking if caller is contract itself.

```
modifier onlyWallet() {
    require(msg.sender == address(this));
    _;
}
```

address(this) is contract address.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found that transactions can send the code as a "byte data" param and thus call any contract's functions. :)

> ```
> addTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
> ```